# Sqlite3-ruby installation issue

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install sqlite3-ruby gem (or as it's now called, simply sqlite3) and whenever I run

> gem install sqlite3

it spits this out

> Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing sqlite3:   ERROR: Failed to
>   build gem native extension.
>
> /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb checking
>   for sqlite3.h... yes checking for
>   sqlite3_libversion_number() in
>   -lsqlite3... yes checking for rb_proc_arity()... no checking for
>   sqlite3_initialize()... yes checking
>   for sqlite3_next_stmt()... yes
>   checking for sqlite3_backup_init()...
>   yes checking for
>   sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
>   checking for
>   sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes
>   checking for
>   sqlite3_load_extension()... yes
>   creating Makefile
>
> make cc -I. -I.
>   -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_SQLITE3_INITIALIZE -DHAVE_SQLITE3_NEXT_STMT -DHAVE_SQLITE3_BACKUP_INIT -DHAVE_SQLITE3_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION -DHAVE_SQLITE3_LOAD_EXTENSION -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/sw/local/include -I/usr/include    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC   -c statement.c In file included from ./sqlite3_ruby.h:42,
>                    from statement.c:1: ./backup.h:7: error: expected
>   specifier-qualifier-list before
>   'sqlite3_backup' make: ***
>   [statement.o] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out

Here's my system specs:
Debian Lenny server
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 3.0.0
Passenger 3.0.7
Sqlite3 3.7.6.2
rubygems 1.3.7

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I needed to enable SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA during compile. Found a nice tutorial [here](http://source.online.free.fr/Linux_HowToCompileSQLite.html)

1. [Download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and Extract sqlite source code.
2. Open `sqlite.c` file and find these lines

   ```
   #ifndef SQLITE_API
   # define SQLITE_API
   #endif
   ```

   add this line below it

   ```
   #define SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
   ```
3. Compile and install

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   make check
   sudo make install #You need to run 'make install' as root or with sudo...
   sudo make clean
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you will need to install either or both of ruby-dev(el) and sqlite3-dev(el). It's -dev on Debian-like systems and -devel on Red Hat-like systems.

Comment: I already have ruby-dev installed. When I try apt-get install sqlite3-dev it responds "Couldn't find package sqlite3-dev" I also tried devel, and it didn't work.

Comment: Well, do a search on sqlite and see what pops up